# How to spy on a nested function in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a function that I am trying to test. I want to test that lambda.invoke is called with the correct arguments, however my test keeps saying that .invoke is never called. I think I am spying incorrectly. How can I spy on the .invoke and the .promise function?

Here is the function:

```
/* Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT
    ENV
    FUNCTION_EMAIL_NAME
  STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    REGION
Amplify Params - DO NOT EDIT */
const stripe = require('stripe');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ region: process.env.REGION });

  const sig = event.headers['Stripe-Signature'];

  let stripeEvent;

  try {
    stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      event.body,
      sig,
      process.env.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`),
    };
  }

  // Handle the event
  switch (stripeEvent.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-case-declarations
      const paymentIntent = stripeEvent.data.object;
      // Then define and call a function to handle the stripeEvent payment_intent.succeeded
      try {
        const result = await lambda
          .invoke({
            FunctionName: process.env.FUNCTION_EMAIL_NAME,
            Payload: JSON.stringify({
              ...event,
              pathParameters: {
                userID: paymentIntent.metadata.userID,
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                user: {
                  emailAddress: paymentIntent.metadata.email,
                },
              }),
            }),
          })
          .promise();

        if (result.StatusCode === 200) {
          return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify('Email successfully sent!'),
          };
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Email failed!', err);
      }
      break;
    // ... handle other stripeEvent types
    default:
      console.log(`Unhandled stripeEvent type ${stripeEvent.type}`);
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
};
```

And here is the failing test:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const stripe = require('stripe');

const { handler } = require('./index');
const event = require('./event.json');

jest.mock('stripe');
jest.mock('aws-sdk');

describe('handler', () => {
  const { env } = process;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    jest.resetModules();
    process.env = {
      ...env,
      REGION: 'us-east-1',
      FUNCTION_EMAIL_NAME: 'example_function_name',
      STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET: 'stripe_test_key',
    };
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    process.env = env;
  });

  it('should call the email lambda if payment intent succeeded', async () => {
    const lambdaSpy = jest.spyOn(AWS, 'Lambda');
    const stripeSpy = jest.spyOn(stripe.webhooks, 'constructEvent');
    const test = jest.fn();

    stripeSpy.mockReturnValue({
      type: 'succeeded',
    });

    lambdaSpy.mockReturnValue({ invoke: test, promise: jest.fn() });

    await handler(event);

    expect(test).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```